PostgreSQL full text search stops returning results
I created a GIN index on a table in PostgreSQL database.  It was created without issue, see below create index statement.  Then I used a select query to search the table, also see below.
create index posts_full_text_search_json_idx on posts using gin (
to_tsvector('english', ((json->>'name')) || ' ' || ((json->>'city')) || ' ' || ((json->>'state')) || ' ' || ((json->>'abbr')) || ' ' || ((json->>'category')) || ' ' || ((json->>'subcategory')))
);

select * from posts where approved=true and (to_tsvector('english', ((json->>'name')) || ' ' || ((json->>'city')) || ' ' || ((json->>'state')) || ' ' || ((json->>'abbr')) || ' ' || ((json->>'category')) || ' ' || ((json->>'subcategory'))) @@ to_tsquery('english', :terms)) limit 200;

:terms is swapped for the search terms via PHP PDO.
This worked right away, no issues, very fast results (about 20-50ms).  But, recently it stopped returning results, no matter what I search for, even if there is guaranteed to be results.
Thanks for reading!
I did some Google searching and did a REINDEX of the index and that did not help, I've restarted the PostgreSQL server, rebooted a few times.  But the query still returns 0 results.  I'm out of solutions.  Has anybody run into this before?

try to rebuild your index

How do you know there are guaranteed to be results? In other words are you sure the data has not changed, been updated and/or deleted ?

Yes, you should add the contents of some of your table rows to the question, as well as the search string, to demonstrate that you really don't get the results you should get. Then somebody can try to reproduce and analyze the problem.

Maybe one of the concatenated field is (always) NULL?

Hi, thanks for the comments.  I've already rebuilt the index once, but I guess I could try again.  I know there are guaranteed to be results because I used to search my privacy page by searching "privacy" and it would return no issues.  This no longer works.  There is a strong possibility that one of the concatenated fields is always null, but that would have been true when it was working too.  I'll consider posting table contents, but I'm starting to lean towards using Apache Solr for text search anyways.  It seems like it would be better and take less strain off the database.

... then try concatenating with concat_ws so Nulls get ignored.

concat_ws appears to be the solution, but I'm having issues creating the index.  It's returning: "ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE" for  this create index: create index posts_full_text_search_idx on posts using gin (
to_tsvector(concat_ws(' ', json->>'name', json->>'city', json->>'state', json->>'abbr', json->>'category', json->>'subcategory'))
);

I'm just going to set the values that are null to default to '' instead and see if search works then.  Thanks all.
